# Cache implementation, the right way to implement second level (File system)

Tags: java, caching

I'm working on the second level of my 2-level cache implementation. 
I'm considering an option of serialization object using standard Java serialization mechanism (Serializable) since this feature is included to JDK. All I know about input objects is that they will implement Serializable interface.
As far as I know Java Input/OutputObject streams support serialization and deserialization of several objects, for example:

```
           ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(
                     new FileOutputStream("output.bin"));

           oout.writeObject(o1);
           oout.writeObject(o2);
           oout.writeObject(o3);
           oout.flush();
           oout.close();

           ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(
                     new FileInputStream("output.bin"));

           Object ob1 = oin.readObject();
           Object ob2 = oin.readObject();
           Object ob3 = oin.readObject();
```

But here I have only one possible order of reading and I haven't ability to add/delete/update random objects from/to the binary file "output.bin". I need this because my idea for second level of my cache is using the same mechanism which is implemented in hashmap/hashtable, so that buckets will be directories and chains will be files.

So I'm looking for right ways of how I can implement such binary serialization, when I will be able to store several objects in file and at the same time will be able to add/delete random object from my binary file. Could you please advise about that?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to use a disk-based cache? Why not a memory cache provided by Ehcache? Disk-based cache sounds bad for performance.

Comment: Yes, it is studying task, so I have to use FS-based cache for second level. The first level is already implemented, it stores objects in RAM. I want to use write-back policy for my 2-level cache, so that last recently used element will go to the second level.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to write to multiple files on disk? Use a Map to get/put the specific file that has your serialized data. File.createTempFile() can get you a unique name for each file.